# Laravel 5.3 Call to a member function groupBy() on null

Tags: methods, fatal-error, laravel-5.3

I'm getting the following error:

> FatalErrorException in EloquentVehicle.php line 30: Call to a member
>   function groupBy() on null

I have the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Project\Frontend\Repo\Vehicle;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EloquentVehicle implements VehicleInterface
{
    protected $vehicle;

    /**
     * EloquentVehicle constructor.
     *
     * @param Model $vehicle
     */
    public function __construct(
        Model $vehicle
    )
    {
        $this->$vehicle = $vehicle;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch unique makes
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fetchMakes()
    {
        return $this->vehicle->groupBy(array('make'))
            ->orderBy('make', 'asc')
            ->get();
    }
}
```

I've checked Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model for the method which is obviously not there, but I don't know what I should be adding to my class so that I can use the groupBy method. The laravel docs say the method exists.

**UPDATE:** Apparently I can't typehint an abstract class. I don't know how else I should be going about using Eloquent to retrieve records. If it helps, below is the code I have for registering the classes to the service container

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Vehicle;
use App\Project\Frontend\Repo\Vehicle\EloquentVehicle;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RepoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Project\Frontend\Repo\Vehicle\VehicleInterface', function($app)
        {
            return new EloquentVehicle(
                new Vehicle
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found my mistake and quite literally lay my face in my palms.

This

```
$this->$vehicle = $vehicle;
```

should be this

```
$this->vehicle = $vehicle;
```